# How to handle binary data containg 3-byte words on Python?

Tags: python, python-3.5, binaryfiles

I need to read binary data structures containing 24 bits little-endian words on a big-endian host. But the [standard Python module `struct` seems to only handle 1-, 2-, 4- and 8-byte words](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/struct.html#format-characters).

Here is a dump of a sample data frame:

```
7F 01 00 00 02 00 00 76 DE 77
-- -------- -------- ----- --
 |    |        |       |    |
 |    |        |       |    |
 |    |        |       |    \ End of frame
 |    |        |       |
 |    |        |       \ 16 bits checksum
 |    |        |
 |    |        \ Second 24 bits word
 |    |
 |    \ First 24 bits word
 |
 \ Start of frame
```

Is there a workaround to read 3-byte words using `struct`?

Comment: By word I assume you mean a binary unit of data right (I.e. processor word size)? Can't you just parse the byte array to get what you want?

Comment: Read it into two variables (1 and 2 bytes) and combine afterwards... alternatively, insert two 0x00 bytes at the proper locations and then read them as 4 byte words.

Comment: Yes @Error. https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/word

Comment: @Peteris indeed. For now, I read them as three bytes and use `int.from_bytes`--but that somehow defeats the purpose of using `struct.Struct`.